# Can a function that executes periodically and when it receives a signal be a critical region?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script executed as a service with a function `do_firewall` that runs every 10 seconds. The same function could be called when the script process receives a SIGUSR1 signal. Is this function a critical region?

The code looks like this:

```
SIGUSR1=10

trap do_firewall SIGUSR1 

do_firewall() {
    # manage some iptables commands implemented in an idempotent 
    # mechanism

    # is this a critical region?
}

###################################################################
# Main block
###################################################################
while true; do
    # If there is no do_firewall process running
    do_firewall
    sleep 10
done
```

Now I have already verified that when SIGUSR1 catch the signal it is managed by the same process running the main loop. My doubt is if it could happen that while I am in the middle of a `do_firewall` function and SIGUSR1 is received, race conditions could occur in it.

I think no, but I am not 100% sure.

In case, do I have to add something like this in the `do_firewall` function:

```
do_firewall() {
    (
        flock -e 200
        # critical region
    ) 200>/var/run/lockfile
}
```

Moreover, is 200 a safe file descriptor to use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's entirely possible for SIGUSR1 to arrive while executing `do_firewall`. It needs to be reentrant if you're going to use it as both a regular function call and a signal handler.

> Moreover, is 200 a safe file descriptor to use?

Sure, use whatever you want. You don't have to go so high. It's fine to use `3`. File descriptor numbers are under your script's control. `3` is most common. Some people start at `10`. Bash starts at `63` and counts down if you use its `>{var}` syntax to auto-assign arbitrary FD numbers.

Comment: The strange thing is that I put a sleep 1000 inside the do_firewall and sent the SIGUSR1 to the script and the handler never activated in that 1000 seconds. In general, how can I test the race condition to verify that flock is really needed?

Comment: Signals are handled in between commands. Try `for ((i=0; i<1000; ++i)); do sleep 1; done` and you'll see the handler called.

Comment: If it receives SIGUSR1 while the main running is in do_firewall, why it didn't run the signal handler when I put the sleep 1000 in do_firewall and during it sent the signal to the script? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: It handles signals *in between* commands. Breaking the sleep up into many small sleeps gives it an opportunity to handle the signal between two `sleep 1` calls whereas a large sleep doesn't.

Comment: One question about this item. This script is basically a monitor script for a cluster. It every 10 seconds check if master node changed (the script run on all the three nodes). The reason why I added the signal handler is that if a switch occurs during the 10-second pause I have to wait 10 seconds before I can run the do_firewall action. However, now I am thinking that this is absolutely useless because the signal handler wait the sleep 10 to complete before it can be run. Is my understanding correct?